# Connect to IP address instead of localhost in php symfony?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP symphony in my project. I try to connect to my IP address instead of local host. The IP address must appear in the URL instead of localhost. But I receive this error: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /Symfony 1.1/web/app_dev.php/municipalite on this server.

this a part of my code :

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
|| isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
|| !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', 
'::1','192.168.1.100'))
) {
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more 
information.');
 }

 $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
 Debug::enable();

 require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

 $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
 $kernel->loadClassCache();
 $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
 $response = $kernel->handle($request);
 $response->send();
 $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Which IP addres are you referring to ? Your public IP address ? Cause from what I see you've got a bit of code to prevent access to your code from outside, so if you try to use your public address, it won't work...

Comment: I want to use this URL /Symfony 1.1/web/app_dev.php/municipalite to read json form. I'm testing my android application.

Comment: Good for you. What about answering my questions ?

Comment: I'm refering to my IP address

Comment: You public one, or your private one  (usually starts with 192.168 ) ?